# Improving React Components

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component below.  I was wondering if there is anything I can do to improve the way the code is written?  I'm trying to learn react and would like to learn how to write code better.  Thanks!

```
component.var JSON_URL = "https://api.example.io/comments.json";

class CommentList extends React.Component {  
constructor() {    
    super();    
    this.state = { comments: [] }  
              }  
componentDidMount() {    
    $.ajax({      
        url: JSON_URL,      dataType: 'json',      success: function(data) {        this.setState({comments: data.comments});      }.bind(this)    });  
};  
render() {    
    return <ul> {this.state.comments.map((comment) => {                  
        return <li>{comment.body}—{comment.author}</li>;                })}           </ul>;  }
}
React.render(<CommentList />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: The first step is to use line breaks and indentation to improve readability.

Comment: You really need eslint. Use recompose instead for the state. Use a stateless function. Put the ajax request in another module.

Answer (score 0):

This code isn't that bad, it just needs to be formatted. Here are some small things that can improve it:

- Make sure everything is formatted correctly
- Extract ajax request into it's own function (should be in it's own module perhaps)
- Might be better to use a different ajax library than jquery (axios, fetch)
- Get rid of constructor since it's not being used and just add state directly in the class

---

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

// move api related things to it's own module
const JSON_URL = 'https://api.example.io/comments.json';
const getComments = (callback) => {
  $.ajax({
    url: JSON_URL,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: (data) => {
      // handle errors
      callback(data.comments);
    }
  });
};

class CommentList extends Component {
  state = {
    comments: []
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    getComments(this._setComments);
  }

  _setComments = (comments) => {
    this.setState({
      comments
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.comments.map((comment) => {
          return (
            <li>
              {comment.body}—{comment.author}
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: `Might be better to use a different ajax library than jquery (axios, fetch)`

Unless he's using jQuery for more than ajax requests in which case it wouldn't be.

Comment: Am curious, why would it be better to use a different library? I do understand that jQuery is built with the intention of manipulating the DOM which is sort of in opposition with the idea of the virtual DOM and ReactJS where unexpected bugs can occur from it. Please advise. @MartinDawson

Comment: MartinDawson true. @fungusanthrax most react apps will not be using jQuery. There's nothing really bad about using jquery for ajax, it's just that if you are only using the ajax part, then it's a lot of overhead. Also promises tend to be easier to work with, so it's nice to use a more modern ajax library. It's not important, just a suggestion.

Comment: @fungusanthrax Because jQuery is a big library and mostly unneeded when using ReactJS. Ajax requests are needed though so you might as well use a small dedicated ajax library to keep small filesize rather than a do-everything like jQuery

Comment: @fungusanthrax I believe the reason why axios (and fetch? unsure as I always use axios personally) are preferred is because they rely on promises rather than callbacks.

Comment: @AustinGreco Ye, I just mentioned it because I don't want him to go and get rid of everything jQuery without understanding why if he's using it in other parts of the app

Answer (score 0):

In general things seem pretty functional here. @Felix King is right with regards to readability - formatting your code makes it easier to critique. One thing I notice right away is the last call in your code is `React.render(<CommentList />, document.getElementById('root'))`, but the `.render` method is only exposed on the `ReactDOM` API. Also, be sure to include your `import`s at the top of your code samples, it makes it easier to figure out what is defined locally and what's coming in from elsewhere. Having your AJAX request in `componentDidMount()` is spot on.